# Changing custom block content through a table in autocad

Tags: autocad

So I have custom blocks, (essentially just labels) and I'm wondering if I can update the content in these blocks using a table (instead of editing the block through the block editor), either an autocad table or maybe through external like excel.. Does anybody know if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is essentially a dynamic block in AutoCAD: you can either use multiple visibility states, with each visibility state containing different block geometry (perhaps with some objects common to all states), or a lookup table parameter to alter constrained properties of the block geometry.

There are many tutorials & documentation in the AutoCAD user manual describing what I have suggested above.